# Why is variance not identified in latent variable models?

Tags: variance, latent-variable

I have seen several times that the variance of the distribution is not identified in latent variable models. For example, in a discrete choice models specified as a probit or with an ordered probit model.

However, I have never seen an explanation for that. Anyone can give me insights or at least a good reference to see the reason?

More specifically,

$y^{*} = x \beta + \epsilon $ and $ y = \mathcal{I}$ $[ y^{*} > 0 ]$ where
$\epsilon$ is a continously distributed variable independent of x.
$\epsilon$ follows a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $\sigma$. Why the variance of the distribution of $\epsilon$ is not identified?